# Access elements of vector<std::unique_ptr<T> > using an iterator?

Tags: c++, vector, move, unique-ptr

I have a class member variable as

`vector<std::unique_ptr<T> > v;`

and a member function where I want to use a `unique_ptr` element of `v` "addressed" by an `iterator` argument. Which one is better?

```
void mem_fun(vector<std::unique_ptr<T> >::iterator it) {
    std::unique_ptr<T> p;
    p = std::move(*it);
    ...
}
```

Or

```
void mem_fun(vector<std::unique_ptr<T> >::iterator it) {
    std::unique_ptr<T>& p = *it;
    ...
}
```

From what I know, it seems the second way just kind of violates the "uniqueness" of `unique_ptr`. But can `std::move()` move `*it` (a reference)? BTW, who truly owns the `unique_ptr` pointers, the class, the member vector, any member function, or what else?

Comment: Is your function only accessing the `T` object? Or does it really need the iterator, I.e. must access multiple `T`s ?

Comment: It does need one iterator.

Answer (score 1):

The first version takes ownership of the `unique_ptr`'s target and leaves the vector with empty `unique_ptr`s. It is unlikely that this is what you want. The second version is confusing. If all you want to do is access the objects managed by the `unique_ptr`s without affecting ownership, simply use the de-rererence operator(s):

```
(*it)->someMethodOfT();
```

Here, the de-reference `(*it)` is to de-reference the iterator, and the `->` is to de-reference the `unique_ptr`.

Remember: the "uniqueness" of a `unique_ptr` refers to its ownership. There's nothing to say the managed object can't be accesses by many non-owners. But it is up to you to decide who takes ownership, depending on the requirements of your application.

Comment: So does "ownership" of `unique_ptr` mean the permission to "set" and "get" the only one copy? Someone else that has no ownership but a reference can "get" but not "set"? Making another copy (e.g. calling `push_back()`) is also a "get" action?

Comment: @WanxinGao No, it means who has control over its lifetime. When the owner dies, the managed object dies too.

Comment: OK! So for `unique_ptr` anyone has the right of use ("get" and "set"), but only one has the ownership (?)

Comment: @WanxinGao Yes, exactly. Ownership can be transferred, but there's only ever one owner.

Answer (score 1):

This [post from Herb Sutter](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/) contains the knowledge to answer your question.

The `unique_ptr` actually defines an 'ownership certificate'.  This ownership is *not copyable*.  When you `move` the `unique_ptr`, this effectively destructs the certificate stored in the `vector.

Therefore, the `vector<unique_ptr<T>>` *owns* the `T`s.

When you just want to do stuff with the `T`s, you should declare your function as

```
void mem_fun(T& t) { ... }
```

And delegate the dereferencing to another function:

```
template<typename It, typename F>
void foreach_deref(It from, It to, F f) {
    std::for_each(from, to, [&](decltype(*from) &pt) {
         f(*pt);
    }
}
```

And use this to call your member function:

```
foreach_deref(begin(v), end(v), [&](T& t) { mem_fun(t); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p = std::move(*it);
```

This means, that `p` is now owning what was owned by `*it` before, and `*it` is no longer owning it(*).

In fact, using `*it` hereafter may cause undefined behaviour, since it has been moved from.

The `unique_ptr` behind the `*it` is owned by the vector.
So in fact you changed your vector. I think this is not what you intended, so better use the reference version.

> [...] it seems the second way just kind of violates the "uniqueness" [...]

Uniqueness in this case means a single owner of the object. You may of course have multiple references to the owner of this object (which is the pointer).

---

(*) This also means that when `p` goes out of scope, the object gets destroyed and deallocated. (Unless you moved from `p` somewhere)

Comment: An undefined behavior? I thought using `*it` might sets the original `unique_ptr` in the vector to `null`?

Comment: Only dereferencing the moved from pointer will cause UB, because after `move(*it)` the pointer is set to `nullptr`. Though merely accessing (via `*it`) doesn't change anything.