# Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) with vector of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr

I have a class containing a vector of unique_ptr as attribute:

```
class C1 {
public:
    void addInVec(unique_ptr<T> elem) {
        vec.push_back(std::move(elem));
    }
    void manipulate() {
        for (auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i) {
            auto res = (*i)->method(); // ERROR: why?
        }
    }
private:
    vector<unique_ptr<T>> vec;
}
```

I call addInVec as follows:

```
c1.addInVec(make_unique<T>());
```

Output when running the code in clion:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

I followed this link for insersion:
[Why can I not push_back a unique_ptr into a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283778/why-can-i-not-push-back-a-unique-ptr-into-a-vector)

I followed this link for access:
[Access elements of vector<std::unique_ptr<T> > using an iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309708/access-elements-of-vectorstdunique-ptrt-using-an-iterator)

I also tried various version of manipulate, all failed:

```
    void manipulate() {
        for (const auto & elem : vec) {
            auto res = elem->method(); // ERROR: why?
        }
    }
```

```
    void manipulate() {
        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
            auto res = vec[i]->method(); // ERROR: why?
        }
    }
```

```
    int res = std::count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const std::unique_ptr<T> & elem) {
        return (elem->method() == 1); // ERROR: why?
    });
```

**What did I miss?**

Comment: The code you have shown looks fine, so the problem is likely in code you have not shown.  For instance, if you are calling `manipulate()` on an invalid `C1` object.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the error in action.

Comment: Ok, I am stupid. The function manipulate was all right I call it on an invalid C1 as proposed by Remy. This came from a silly mistake in a constructor not presented here (swapping two lines of this constructor solved the issue, i.e. initialising the C1 before using it...)